# Magento2 Success msg not getting displayed after redirection

Tags: magento2, messages

Magento2 I need to redirect to home page & display success msg after Submitting custom form in cart page.

I have written below code in my custom controller file but msg doesn't print on Home page only page gets redirect.

```
$this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                      __("Thank you for submitting your product enquiry . Our team will reach out to you as soon as possible.")
                            );

$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create(); 
/** @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect **/
return $resultRedirect->setPath('/');
```

Comment: there must be some customization done for the home page.

Answer (score 0):

check below code

```
public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        try {
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Submitted Successfully.'));
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('review/customer/review');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('Something went wrong while.'));
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        }

        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
```